# Error on build cpp project in android studio in linux

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-studio, android-ndk

I installed android sdk, platform and build tools and NDK in my ArchLinux to develop with android-studio and c++. I've created a simple "hello world program" just to start but it is not compiling. The error message on build returned by android studio is **"A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. executing external native build for cmake /home/fabio/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloWorld/app/CMakeLists.txt"**

On the **CMakeError.log**:

> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /home/fabio/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloWorld/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/opt/android-sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja" "cmTC_be251"
>
> [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_be251.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
>   FAILED: /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  -target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-15/arch-arm   -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_be251.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/fabio/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloWorld/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
>
> **/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

For the creation of the project, I just checked the option "**Include c++ support**" and started with a **blank activity**, changed no code then.

**Edit**
 Tryied instlalling **libtinfo** as suggested in [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21309/error-while-loading-libtinfo-so-5-solved) thread but didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same issue. Quite many of the other distributions often have outdated packages. They still use ncurses 5 instead of ncurses 6 (libtinfo seems to belong to ncurses). Assuming, that the android ndk's version of clang was built on such a system, it was worth a try to use ncurses 5. From the **A**rch **U**ser **R**epositories I was able to install the latest version of [ncurses5-compat-libs](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/) (and I also installed the 32bit version: [lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs/)). This solved the problem for me. If you have it installed already, try reinstalling or updating it, if it is outdated.